# How a 3rd party can verify if a paypal payment went through?

Tags: paypal

I have two people disputing about a paypal payment, one says he sent the money and the other says he didn't receive.

I have to judge which one is saying the truth without having access to their paypal account, since screenshots can be tempered with I can't rely on those either.
The sender provided a transaction ID, is there any way I can use that to verify the transaction?

Is there anything else I can try and resolve this?

Comment: Shouldn't PayPal be handling this dispute?

Comment: for that there need to be a transaction, how the guy that says he didn't receive the money can start a dispute if there's a chance there wasn't any transaction to begin with?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PayPal's dispute mechanisms, but if they're not able to settle a simple dispute like this, no one else is going to be able to either.